# Search for row of points in a list (involves recursive loops)

Tags: python, loops

basically, I'd like to find if any points line up with any combination in a list, but I can't seem to think of a good way to do this (12 levels of loops would be a bit confusing). The code below will search the combinations and determine which contain the point, then I'd like it to search those resulting combinations to see if there's 4 points in a line (it'll eventually be a 4x4x4 cube when I get the display sorted, so the combinations are all possible lines you can make)

```
#bit not in the code, just here so you can see the structure
points=[1,4,1],[4,4,3],[2,4,1],[3,4,1],[4,4,1]
possibleCombinations = []
possibleCombinations.append(['(4, 4, 1)', '(3, 4, 1)', '(2, 4, 1)', '(1, 4, 1)'])
possibleCombinations.append(['(4, 4, 4)', '(3, 4, 3)', '(2, 4, 2)', '(1, 4, 1)'])
possibleCombinations.append(['(1, 1, 3)', '(2, 1, 3)', '(3, 1, 3)', '(4, 1, 3)'])

#finds which combinations contain the point
for i in points:
    coordinates = (i[0], i[1], i[2])
    for j in range(len(possibleCombinations)):
        if any(str(coordinates) in s for s in possibleCombinations[j]):
            print possibleCombinations[j]
```

I've thought of only processing newly added points and figuring out the possible combinations they lie in and test for other points connected, but so far I've only managed to do a calculation of where the point is situated (corner/edge/side/middle).

```
'''
combinations:
each corner has 7
each edge has 4
each side has 3 (with 2 diagonal lines running through)
each middle has 2 (with 20 diagonal lines running through)
'''
#temp coordinate
x = 1
y = 1
z = 1

#calculate location
locationNum = 0
if x == 1 or x == 4:
    locationNum += 1
else:
    locationNum -= 1
if y == 1 or y == 4:
    locationNum += 10
else:
    locationNum -= 10
if z == 1 or z == 4:
    locationNum += 100
else:
    locationNum -= 100

if locationNum == 111:
    position = "corner"
elif locationNum == 109 or locationNum == 91 or locationNum == -89:
    position = "edge"
elif locationNum == -109 or locationNum == -91 or locationNum == 89:
    position = "side"
elif locationNum == -111:
    position = "middle"
```

It's getting late, and I've started multiple attempts which haven't worked out, so any help you guys could give would be appreciated. I was thinking about having a separate calculation for all the positions, which I could maybe do, but the diagonal lines cutting through kinda complicate this a little, and then there's still the matter of checking for 4 points in a line.

Thanks :)

Comment: It *must* be recursive?

Comment: i've read 2 times, and still doesnt get what you are saying

Comment: What do you mean by "12 levels of loops"?

Comment: Ah sorry about not being too clear. It doesn't have to be recursive, but I'm not entire sure how to do it otherwise.
And Lucas, basically, I have a 4x4x4 cube, and points within this cube, and I'd like to find if any 4 points make a line (this shows an idea of the combinations I'd need to check for two different points - http://imm.io/1jpIE)

It seems like simple stuff, I had no idea it'd be this hard figuring it out :P